# BSTR conversion to UTF-8

Tags: c++, windows, utf-8

I'm working with UIAutomation and I'm struggling with the localized BSTRs. I'm in Germany, so there are some special characters that are represented funny in the BSTRs. I'm logging the information and need to have them in UTF-8 to process later on.

I tried already every version of the answers that I could find regarding to WideCharToMultiByte, but that's just converting the funny character into an even funnier one. I'd really appreciate if anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong, it's really bugging me.

So I tried both of the following versions and got both times this result (the upper one is the converted one, the lower the original one):

[image: Screenshot]

The first word should be "Schaltfläche" and the second "Fünf".

My tried code:

```
BSTR* origin;
_bstr_t originWrapper(*origin);
char* originChar = originWrapper;
size_t len = strlen(originChar) + 1;
int room = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, originChar, -1, NULL, 0);
wchar_t* unicodeString = (wchar_t*)malloc((sizeof(wchar_t))*room);
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, originChar, -1, unicodeString, room);

int size_needed = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, unicodeString, -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
char* utf8Char = (char*) malloc(size_needed);
WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, unicodeString, -1, utf8Char, size_needed, NULL, NULL);
```

and

```
BSTR* origin;
_bstr_t originWrapper(*origin);
int size_needed = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, originWrapper, SysStringByteLen(*origin), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
std::string resultingString(size_needed, 0);
WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, *origin, SysStringByteLen(*origin), &resultingString[0], size_needed, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: Rule number one of debugging encoding problems: always look at the actual bytes, because printing may add additional encoding problems. What are the bytes reported by your `WideCharToMultiByte` calls?

Comment: `BSTR` are already `wchar_t *`, why are you treating them as if they were local-codepage narrow strings?

Comment: `BSTR` is already a pointer (to a wide character string), so `BSTR *` is a little strange.

Comment: `BSTR`s are encoded using UTF16-LE. Calling `WideCharToMultiByte` with `CP_UTF8` produces a UTF-8 encoded string. Since we have no idea, how you determine that those are *"even funnier"*, we cannot help you there. The bug is in the part where you attempt to output/display/observe the result.

Comment: The pointer comes because it's copied from a function that gets it as an input variable, I oversaw that and I'll edit it. Sorry. 
@MatteoItalia the first try? That was just because the second didn't work and I tried the snipped from another question. Didn't really thought about it obviously. And for the even funnier looking characters I included the screenshot because I couldn't copy and paste it unfortunately.

First of all I'm going to look into the bytes now and provide you that information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`BSTR` is a pointer to UTF-16 (`WCHAR`) character data, preceded by the string length. So, your roundtrip through narrow strings is misguided, you should straight use `WideCharToMultiByte`:

```
std::string BSTRtoUTF8(BSTR bstr) {
    int len = SysStringLen(bstr);
    // special case because a NULL BSTR is a valid zero-length BSTR,
    // but regular string functions would balk on it
    if(len == 0) return "";
    int size_needed = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, bstr, len, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    std::string ret(size_needed, '\0');
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, bstr, len, ret.data(), ret.size(), NULL, NULL);
    return ret;
}
```

To check the validity of the conversion *don't* output the result to the console, as it doesn't support UTF-8 output by default (it interprets narrow strings not even as in `CP_ACP`, but in `CP_OEM`, go figure). Instead, write the output to a file and check it with a reliable editor supporting UTF-8.

Comment: Thank you, it's still not 100% right in the log file yet, but that seems to be another additional problem. At least it's now UTF-8 conform and does not throw an exception anymore :) Oh and my issue was that I forgot, that the console doesn't support UTF-8 -.-